# How to use agregate on update in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I would like to change value in table dynamically i mean if value in column is 0 set 1 and reverse when 1 set 0. I noticed that when i use mysql query:

```
UPDATE table set column = ABS(column-1)
```

its working but how to implement that into Laravel eloquent (update)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DB::raw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions) to add raw database expressions anywhere in your query.

```
DB::table('table')->update(['column' => DB::raw('ABS(column-1)')]);
```